Is there a way to prove ownership of church land?
Most Church of England land has been church property longer than the Land Registry has existed, and no results are provided on their search.
Is there a way to acquire paperwork that demonstrates church ownership, for example to allow an electricity network such as SSEN to undertake work?  Suppose the church on the land has been present and in use since the 1100s.

Seems like SSEN would have dealt with such a paperwork situation in the past.

@BlueDogRanch You would have thought so, but they do not have a solution.

I didn't think much of that is necessary in the UK. Because of the common law doctrine of adverse possession, simply using the land with no one else claiming the land for a while (a period of several years) is enough to make the claim that the land is legally yours, whether you were the original owner or not.

@uberhaxed: It's more complicated when it comes to church land. See, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chancel_repair_liability

The Church Commissioners might be able to help you.

I've had a similar problem. As PeterM says in a comment below, this is an XY problem. The utility has internal procedures to stop it getting sued when it digs a trench on some land, thinking it has permission from the owner, but in fact only having permission from the guy next door. The real problem here is: how to make the clerks in the works clearance department escalate this issue to someone with authority to override their usual procedures. This is probably best done by invoking the utilities' legal obligations to provide a service rather than trying to do their legal legwork for them.

Have you spoken to your diocesan chancellor's office? Note that a faculty is required before works are undertaken in churches and churchyards.

There is no requirement and little benefit to registering church land
You must register when property is:

bought
gifted
inherited
received in exchange for other property or land
mortgaged

This system was a deliberate choice so that the costs of registration would only be imposed when a transfer of title or other significant event was happening to the property.
However, none of these things ever happen to church property. Or, for that matter, other property that rarely, if ever, changes hands: government property, parks and reserves, railways, ports, airports etc. Currently, this amounts to about 15% of the land in England and Wales (because Scotland and Northern Ireland have their own systems).
Proving ownership the old way
This only comes up, as far as the law is concerned, when there is a dispute over title. Then the issue is solved by testimony and evidence and the person with the more convincing case wins.
The church has kept very good records for an unusually long time, so it’s possible that that they have a title deed and can demonstrate ownership back to time immemorial, 1189.
However, that isn’t actually necessary. If the church (or anyone else) has been in possession of the land unchallenged for 12 years (30 or 60 years for Crown lands), then all they have to do is prove that and the land is theirs. Proving occupancy since 2012 is likely to be easier than proving ownership since 1189.

Proving ownership is one thing. Often, however, what is really at issue is the precise location of a boundary of what is owned, which could be harder to prove.

@ohwilleke: It depends on the facts. If there's a fence on the property line, then it can serve as evidence of possession and use, especially if you can prove that the fence was put up and/or repaired more than 12 years ago (which could be as little as one receipt). If there's no fence, then you can maybe bring in the landscapers and have them testify about what grass they mowed etc., but I imagine it's difficult to get good testimony for the entire 12-year period.

@Kevin Another option would be to get the mets and bound of all of the adjacent privately owned parcels that are in the Land Registry.

A confounding factor could be that possession itself is considered a proof of ownership in the English common law.
Another confounding factor is that there isn't necessarily just one form of "ownership", in the sense of a single legal person with complete authority and sovereign rights to a parcel of land, from the heavens to the bowels of the earth.
The Statute of Westminster 1275 defined the year 1189 as the threshold of "time immemorial" for the common law, so any land continuously possessed by the church since before then could not possibly be defeated by any superior written title.
In general though, if a utility wished to do work on church property, they would simply ask the church.

"if a utility wished to do work on church property, they would simply ask the church" in this case they require documentary proof of ownership before they will lay the cable.  There is a suspicion there is a management directive after a mistake.

@User65535 Your comment makes this question sound like an XY problem.  The ultimate goal is not to prove that the church owns the land, but to get the utility company to lay the cable.

@User65535: In which case, it might suffice to give them a copy of any document from your archives that "looks official enough". After all, the goal is not to prove ownership, but to get the clerk to fill the check box and move on with the next step in the process. Another option would be to escalate the issue to someone who is high enough in the utility company's management chain and has the authority to make decisions in unusual cases.

The National Archives' Land and property ownership: enrolment and registration of title 1227-c1930 page may be of use, at least as a starting point for more research.

Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

You're probably right. I had originally typed the info in the comment box, but was right on the cusp between risking "don't answer in comments" and "[an answer] needs more detail". Will try and find some time to add some details.

My guideline is to imagine the Q&A printed out, so that links aren't followable.  If the answer is useful in that format, it contains the necessary detail.  See also Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?

Before the Land Registry was created, the U.K., like the U.S. today, used a recording system. Deeds were recorded with the deed recording office and indexed in a grantor-grantee index. Those records probably still exist somewhere, even if the property hasn't been added to the land registry, probably as part of the archives of the same office that handles the Land Registry.
Another place where records of ownership are probably kept, or at least information on where the records can be found, is in the records of the bishop who is responsible for the church in question.

See edit, the church has been there since the 1100's.  Can you give an indication what could have caused the creation of the records?

I am fairly sure that using a deed recording office was a rarity in England. I have never heard of it, and I actually did advise on unregistered conveyancing when a younger barrister and was a land law specialist and later sat as a property judge. If deed recording offices were significant, that was utterly unknown to anyone who taught me or I worked with.

To prove ownership of historic church land, try these:
Contact the local diocese for church records.
Check historical archives for old documents.
Consult the Land Registry for guidance.
Seek legal advice if needed.
These should help with acquiring the necessary paperwork.

This answer doesn't really add anything, and reads a little like AI. Can you flesh it out a bit more?

Yeah, this sounds more like advice than a factual response.
